# Existing App is SPA but When Converted to Universal, Firebase.storage() was Not Found

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an app built in nuxt.js, vue.js and firebase and in default it is built as a `Single Page Application` but I want to convert it to a `Server-side-rendered` app. But when I changed the mode, firebase does not recognize `storage()` anymore.

Here is my `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
export default {
  mode: "universal",
  target: "server",
  // Some other configuration
   ....
}
```

And here is my `firebase.js` file

```js
import firebaseTmp from "firebase";
import firebaseErrorsJa from "~/plugins/firebaseErrorsJa";

const config = process.env.firebaseConfig;

if (!firebaseTmp.apps.length) {
  firebaseTmp.initializeApp(config);
}
　　　
const storage = firebaseTmp.storage();
//some other initialization
  
//also location is not found also
if (location.hostname === "localhost") {
  db.settings({
    host: "localhost:8000",
    ssl: false
  });

  functions.useEmulator("localhost", 5001)
  auth.useEmulator('http://localhost:9099/');
}

export { db, firebase, firestore, auth, storage, firestoreTimestamp, serverTimestamp, functions, 
firebaseErrors }
```

Has anyone encountered this problem? Why is it like this?

AN UPDATE:
I already fixed the error. I just had to add this line, `import 'firebase/storage';` to my `firebase.js` file. Now I have to fix another thing in the same file because `location` is undefined. Here is the code snippet..

```js
if (location.hostname === "localhost") {
  db.settings({
    host: "localhost:8000",
    ssl: false
  });

  functions.useEmulator("localhost", 5001)
  auth.useEmulator('http://localhost:9099/');
}
```

Comment: What is your version of Nuxt ? Maybe `firebase` is not compatible with SSR. Did you tried the Nuxt module ? https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/service-options/storage

Comment: Nuxt version is 2.13.0. I also added the services in my nuxt.config.js file but it still does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "I also added the services" ?

Comment: it is in this link actually.. [link](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/guide/options) . But its okay. I already fixed that part. I just had to add this line `import "firebase/storage";` in my firebase.js file

Comment: Not sure how your code works before so. Where does location comes from ? Is it related to this ? https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/service-options/functions#location

Comment: I found the documentation [here](http://console.firebase.google.com/u/1/?pli=1) . This is when we use our firebase emulators. I dont get why it does not define the `object` from my code.